Greenbone installation error of postgresql
I did sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade before installing gvm successfully.
however, running sudo gvm-setup exits with the following errors of postgresql:
[>] Starting PostgreSQL service
[-] ERROR: The default PostgreSQL version (14) is not 17 that is required by libgvmd
[-] ERROR: libgvmd needs PostgreSQL 17 to use the port 5432
[-] ERROR: Use pg_upgradecluster to update your PostgreSQL cluster
I dont understand what could be possibly going wrong, i followed the instruction on their official website and i cant find a workaround this problem.

As the log stated you will need version 17 to have libgvmd to work.
